# Is Matlab 'phase command' unwrapped?

Tags: matlab, phase

When I `lookfor phase` the result is

> phase  Computes the phase of a complex vector 
>   PHI=phase(G)
>
> ```
> G is a complex-valued row vector and PHI is returned as its
> phase (in radians), with an effort made to keep it continuous
> over the pi-borders.
> ```

This implies that the output of the method is unwrapped but if I try `unwrap(phase(PHI))`,
the output becomes different. Why is that? Does not `phase` already return unwrapped phase?

Note: `phase` is in the System Identification Toolbox
The `phase`command is not found in the MATLAB Documentation. Just shows up with `lookfor phase`

Comment: I cant find the function in the documentation! http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/ident/functionlist.html
Can you share a link?

Comment: I could not find it, either. If you have System Identification Toolbox , please use `lookfor logspace`. Maybe I should use a different word other than 'documentation'

Comment: But... If there is no documentation...You should not use that function... Why dont you use `angle` ?

Comment: I could not agree more @AnderBiguri . However, `phase` is awkwardly required to use. That's why I am questioning about this command.

Comment: If I do `lookfor phase` I get arounf 200 results :( However, I found one of them that i literally called phase, and I get your message. BUT! if I go to the help suggested there, I get a phase function from data adquisition toolbox, not system identification toolbox!

Comment: However, I must say, that I only get result  `[-pi pi]` with `phase` adn therefore the same with unwrap. Can you post a numerical example where you get different values?